# AngularJS - Change text continuously from a array of strings

Tags: javascript, angularjs, carousel

Is there a way to simulate a carousel of text in my angular controller?

Such as:

```
 //html 
 <span> {{ notes }}</span>

 //angular controller

   var i = 0;
   var array = ["A", "B", "C", "D", "E"];

   while (true) {
       $scope.notes = array[i];
       i = i + 1;
       if (i = array.length - 1) {
           i = 0;
       }
   }
```

Is there a way to do this without a infinite loop? I am trying to create a carousel of text vertically and having fade animations in a CSS class to try and accomplish this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you are looking for [$interval](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$interval).

```
var i = 0;
var array = ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E'];

$interval(function () {
  $scope.notes = array[i++ % array.length];
}, 1000);
```

See example here: https://jsfiddle.net/8pLwjybf/3/

Answer (score 0):

I would use setInterval, instead of an infinite loop, and use % to wrap your index

```
var i = 0;
var array = ["A", "B", "C", "D", "E"];

function next() {
  var idx = ++i % array.length;
  $scope.notes = array[idx];
}

setInterval(next, someTime);
```